# Rails 4: Clean Texts from Wysiwyg editors on ElasticSearch index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, wysiwyg, tire

I have an index called `offers` im trying to perform a full text search with Elastic search, Im using the gem Tire.

My model has a description field, however the input of this field is a Wysiwyg editor, so when I check the indexed data on ElasticSearch index the `description` field has all the `<p>`'s the new lines `\n` and many other code characters like this:

`<h2>Qu&eacute; hay en la caja:</h2>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Tablet KRONO 7021</li>\r\n\t<li>Cable USB</li>\r\n\t<li>`

My question is: Do you think that the text needs to be decoded in ElasticSearch in order to do not affect full-text search?

Comment: What is the analyzer you're using for that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should decode your text. Two options:

Save text as two different fields - one with WYSIWYG tags, and the other one clean and search against that column - problematic if you have A LOT of entries.

Use Elastic's `"char_filter":  [ "html_strip" ]` option. You will have to try it out manually to see how well it works in your case.

Comment: I just have a question, I already added a custom analyzer with `"char_filter":  [ "html_strip" ]` however when checking the indexed data on elasticsearch the text is still the same, so I don't know if Im doing something wrong or if it's just like that, analyzers don't show result on index?

Comment: have you reindexed your documents?

Comment: Im using Elastic Search 2.4, yes I reindixed, I mean, should I be able to see it decoded on the index?

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585971/elasticsearch-and-tire-how-to-use-html-strip

Comment: I created a new question with my doubts if you can solve my doubts regarding analyzers. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41883725/3700798